# order-by case sorting in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am unable to understand how the case functions correctly, I have a table called sales, this is how I interrogate it and this is a small fragment of the output, I am trying to do a challenge from a sql book

```
use TSQL2012
select custid,orderid, shippeddate
from sales.orders
```

This is the output ( small part of it)

```
85  10248   2006-07-16 00:00:00.000
79  10249   2006-07-10 00:00:00.000
34  10250   2006-07-12 00:00:00.000
80  11069   2008-05-06 00:00:00.000
44  11070   NULL
46  11071   NULL
```

So what I had to do is to get all the rows where the Customer ID ( custid ) is 20 AND to sort in an ascending order the shippeddate with the NULLs being placed at the end. This is what I've tried to do:

```
select orderid, shippeddate
from sales.orders
where custid = 20
order by 
    case when shippeddate is null then shippeddate end desc,
    case when shippeddate is not null then shippeddate end asc
```

It returns absolutely nothing, so after I cracked I decided to look on the internet for the solution, and this is it :

```
use TSQL2012
select orderid, shippeddate
from sales.orders
where custid = 20
order by case
when shippeddate is null  then 1 else 0 end, shippeddate ;
```

What is 1 and 0 supposed to do ? They are not true/false, they are not ordinal positions, how can they replace `desc` respectively `asc` ? I am pretty new to SQL, sorry for the "explain me the code cos' i'm too dumb question"

Comment: They're just literal integers. 1 = 1 and 0 = 0. 1 sorts after 0. You're looking for complexity where none exists.

Comment: 1 is greater than 0, that's the only "magic" here. It's basically divides all records into two groups where `shippeddate is null` records come last.

Comment: Still a bit confuse about that fact that I can group things in this way, never saw something like this. Thanks

Comment: @ExtremeSwat: it's not a group as in a `Group By`, it's just the major sort argument. So it translates the boolean like `shippeddate is null` to something that can be used for sorting. You can also use `then 100 else 99 end` or `then 0 else 1 end desc`. Default is `Asc` and `0` is lower than `1`.

Comment: Try putting `DESC` after `... then 1 else 0 end` and see what happens. You should be able to figure it out by yourself.

Comment: If you have 2012+, you can put `NULLS FIRST`/`NULLS LAST`, which would simplify all of this...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - you probably mistook SQL Server with Oracle. There is no such thing in the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think about the construct `case when shippeddate is null  then 1 else 0 end` as a derived column, which isn't returned to the client via select list, but is used for sorting.

You can look at it this way:

```
select orderid, shippeddate, case when shippeddate is null  then 1 else 0 end as [SortCol1]
from sales.orders
where custid = 20
order by SortCol1, shippeddate;
```